# ZXing portrait in Android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

I need to use ZXing scan in portrait mode.
I read this http://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/detail?id=178 but in my Android 2.3.6 device the camera preview doesn't work: if i move my phone to right the camera scroll to top.
How can i solve it ?

In Android 2.2 device it's ok.

Thank you